# Rails 4 - passing variable to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial and have come across a problem while trying to pass variables to partials.

My `_user` partial is as follows

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
```

I would like to pass in a number for the size value. I am trying as follows without any luck.

```
<%= render @users, :locals => {:size => 30} %>
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You need the full render partial syntax if you are passing locals

```
<%= render @users, :locals => {:size => 30} %>
```

Becomes

```
<%= render :partial => 'users', :collection => @users, :locals => {:size => 30} %>
```

Or to use the new hash syntax

```
<%= render partial: 'users', collection: @users, locals: {size: 30} %>
```

Which I think is much more readable

Comment: Thanks @jamesw, But images are still size 52. Is it because I have the size set to 52 explicitly in the partial?

Comment: Yes actually, you are overriding the previous value of size.

Comment: You can omit the `locals` hash to use the short version like so: `<%= render @users, size: 30 %>`

Answer (score 188):

From the Rails api on [PartialRender](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html):

> **Rendering the default case**
>
> If you're not going to be using any of the options like collections or layouts, you can also use the short-hand defaults of render to render partials.

Examples:

```
# Instead of <%= render partial: "account" %>
<%= render "account" %>

# Instead of <%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
<%= render "account", account: @buyer %>

# @account.to_partial_path returns 'accounts/account', so it can be used to replace:
# <%= render partial: "accounts/account", locals: { account: @account} %>
<%= render @account %>

# @posts is an array of Post instances, so every post record returns 'posts/post' on `to_partial_path`,
# that's why we can replace:
# <%= render partial: "posts/post", collection: @posts %>
<%= render @posts %>
```

So, you can use pass a local variable `size` to render as follows:

```
<%= render @users, size: 50 %>
```

and then use it in the `_user.html.erb` partial:

```
<li>
    <%= gravatar_for user, size: size %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user %>
</li>
```

Note that `size: size` is equivalent to `:size => size`.

Comment: The second render, the one without locals, saved my life. Thanks

Comment: This shorthand, not being mentioned in [Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), made it really confusing. Almost like they want to hide it.

Answer (score 11):

Either

```
render partial: 'user', locals: {size: 30}
```

Or

```
render 'user', size: 30
```

To use `locals`, you need `partial`. Without the `partial` argument, you can just list variables directly (not within `locals`)

Comment: this is the answer in 2023!

Answer (score 5):

### Don't use `locals` in Rails 4.2+

In Rails 4.2 I had to remove the `locals` part and just use `size: 30` instead. Otherwise, it wouldn't pass the local variable correctly.

For example, use this:

```
<%= render @users, size: 30 %>
```

Comment: Quick clarification on this. If, for some reason, you need to specify the `partial` key, such as when using a Array of objects that don't match the partial, you still need to use `locals`. But when using this shorthand method, you _need_ to omit `locals`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JavaScript to render then use `escape_JavaScript("<%=render partial: partial_name, locals=>{@newval=>@oldval}%>");`

Answer (score 2):

ou are able to create local variables once you call the render function on a partial, therefore if you want to customize a partial you can for example render the partial `_form.html.erb` by:

```
<%= render 'form', button_label: "Create New Event", url: new_event_url %>
<%= render 'form', button_label: "Update Event", url: edit_event_url %>
```

this way you can access in the partial to the label for the button and the URL, those are different if you try to create or update a record.
finally, for accessing to this local variables you have to put in your code `local_assigns[:button_label]` (`local_assigns[:name_of_your_variable]`)

```
<%=form_for(@event, url: local_assigns[:url]) do |f|  %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages_events' %>
<%= f.label :title ,"Title"%>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'%>
  <%=f.label :date, "Date"%>
  <%=f.date_field :date, class: 'form-control'  %>
  <%=f.label :description, "Description"%>
  <%=f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control'  %>
  <%= f.submit local_assigns[:button_label], class:"btn btn-primary"%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically a little different but it looks cleaner in my opinion:

```
render 'my_partial', locals: { title: "My awesome title" }

# not a big fan of the arrow key syntax
render 'my_partial', :locals => { :title => "My awesome title" }
```