# Controller action for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, partials

I was trying to create an action for one of the partials in my rails application, but wondered how to name it.  Does it have the underscore at the beginning? Like:

```
def _my_partial

end
```

or no underscore?  Not mentioned in the [controllers guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html for explanation of how partials are used in views, and how they link to the controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

A `partial` is a piece of view which is embedded in the main view or within another `partial`. The purpose of a `partial` is typically for re-use or to making view code cleaner.

If you need to use an action to render a partial, then it's probably better to either:

- make your partial into a view, or
- create a view to embed your partial.
  See [Rails 4 - passing variable to partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial)

Comment: For option 2, will the partial inherit the functionality of the view in which it is displayed?  eg if I define a blog = Blog.find(params[:id]) variable in my index view, will a partial displayed in the index know what blog is? Edit: removed @ symbols

Comment: You will have to pass in to the partial any specific values. Added a link to the answer.