# Partials action inheretance rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, partials

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268659/controller-action-for-partials?noredirect=1#comment44895316_28268659) about creating an action for a partial.  It was suggested that I either include a partial in a view (what partials are for), or make it its own view (no longer a partial).  This has led me to ask a distinct question:

Do partials inherit actions from the views in which they are displayed?

Edit to answer first comment:

What I mean is if I have an index action and index view, and I display a partial in that view, will the partial understand the variables I define for the index action?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "inherit actions" ?

Comment: Edited to answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

based on the edit:

Theoreticaly, your partial knows about the instance variables defined in your controller. So you can simply call them in the partial.
However it's more commong, and a good practise, to actually pass them along to the partial as variables: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials
See option 3.4.4 : Passing local variables.

This makes your partial more usable.
Otherwise you can only reuse the partial if you redeclare the variable in all controllers using this partial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you partial that is a part of index template will know the same variables as index.

Keep in mind, it is not good practice to keep the partials dependent on instance variables since they can be reused anywhere! In order to remove the dependency send them in the partial as a local variable

So your index.html.slim (or html, or erb, whatever you use), can have:

```
render 'some_partial', items: @products
```

or somewhere else where you might call it:

```
render 'some_partial', items: @active_products
```

or as a full notation:

```
render partial: 'some_partial', locals: { items: @products }
```

hope you got the idea ;)