# Rails Instance Variable Accessibility Inside Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may be a silly question, but I'm curious to know how it works. Here is the scenario:

**Controller**

```
def some_method
  @abc = true
  render :template => "show", :layout => "lightbox"
end
```

Now, when I try to access the instance variable **@abc** inside layout, it comes out to be **nil**. But, for following scenario:

**Controller**

```
def some_method
  render :template => "show", :layout => "lightbox"
end
```

**View** (show.html.haml)

```
- @abc = true
```

The variable is accessible inside layout.

My question is:

Why is it different that I define an instance variable inside **view**, it's accessible in layout, but if the same variable is defined in **controller** instead of **view**, it's not accessible and come as **nil**?

Comment: But, it comes as **nil**, that is what goes beyond my understanding

Comment: You should be able to access your @abc variable defined in controller in your views. Can you show your layout?

Comment: Are you sure that `@abc` is not assigned `nil` before accessing in layout. Check all references or `@abc` in your application

Comment: @AmitPatel I'm sure that it's not assigned nil. BTW I use **byebug** gem to debug and also tried inspecting the variable using **Rails.logger.info**

Comment: Then I guess you are still missing something; otherwise, you would not ask that question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case: When you use `render` in the controller action, it does not inherit the controller action scope automatically. You would have to pass the variable to the `render` call. Something like:

```
render  :template => "show", :layout => "lightbox",  :locals => {abc: @abc}
```

In the view template you would be able to access the variable `abc` (without the `@`), containing the controller `@abc` variable contents

---

In the second case: when processing the template "show", rails is creating the `@abc` variable inside the view scope. So you can access it.

---

The answers provided in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial) can help you understand what is happening. And the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) are also a good reference for you