# Rails: How to DRY up multiple use of a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, layout, dry

Like to DRY up the following code. Created a partial `_user.html.erb`, which is called either by the **users** view via

1. `<%= render @users %>`

and by the **groups** view via

2. `<%= render partial: 'users/user', collection: @mailgroup.users, as: :user %>`

The partial `_user.html.erb` is:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:tr, user) do %>
  <td><%= user.id %></td>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id, true %></td>
  <td><%= user.firstname %></td>
  <td><%= user.lastname %></td>
  <td><%= user.function %></td>
  <td><%= user.company %></td>
  <td><%= user.appendix %></td>
  <td><%= user.city %></td> 
  <td>
    <%= link_to button1 ...     %>
    <%= link_to button2 ...     %>
    <%= link_to button3 ...     %>
    <%= link_to button4 ...     %>    
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Now I like this partial having rendered once with all columns (call 1.), and also with a subset of columns (call 2.). Especially like to hide the `check_box_tag` in the second column.

I searched around and was confused at the end how to solve: With different layouts? How would I have to do it with partials? Or with checking first from what controller the call comes from? (This doesn't sound very satisfying to me).

In general: How to call the same partial with different subset of columns without maintaining different copies of that partial?

Comment: Oh man I wish I had more time so I could dig into this. Short version is you might consider the presenter pattern. I'm working on a project where, for a particularly complex set of views, I've moved **essentially all** of the logic out of views and into plain old ruby objects. And now my life is so much better. It's the most amazing view desiccant you've ever seen. Check out Ryan Bates' RailsCast - Presenters from Scratch. That's a pretty good starting place. If you're interested, I can try to come back for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use layouts for partials and I agree that checking for controller source is a code smell. I would consider using another local to check if the fields are to be displayed which could be set in the "calling" view e.g.

```
<%= render @users, locals: {show_buttons: false} %>

<%= render partial: 'users/user', collection: @mailgroup.users, as: :user, show_buttons: true %>
```

and used in the user partial

```
<% if show_buttons %>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id, true %></td>
<% end %>
```

You could dry this out further with a helper method

```
<td><%= user.id %></td>
<%= check_box(user, show_buttons)

module UsersHelper

  def check_box(user, show_buttons)
    if show_buttons
      content_tag(:td) do
        content_tag(:option, "user_ids[]", value: user.id )
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks margo, I had to adapt your solution slightly the following way: The call `<%= render @users, locals: {show_buttons: false} %>` unfortunately doesn't work when calling with locals, need to fully write the call as `<%= render partial: 'user', collection: @users, locals: {show_check: false} %>` (described in this SO answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial].
Then in the helper I changed from `content_tag(:option...)`  to  `check_box_tag(...)`

Comment: FWIW you can use partials as layouts, simply by calling `render layout: 'user'` and passing it a block instead of `render partial: 'user'` with no block.