# I am using Rails Admin gem but I am unable to post my product without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use ajax with rails_admin gem but I am unable to use it.

Created a `_product.html.erb`, `index.html.erb`, `index.js.erb`

In **index.html.erb**

```
<div id="products"><%= render "products" %> </div>
```

In **index.js.erb**

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("products")) %>");
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to pass the local variable:

[Rails 4 - passing variable to partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial)

Something like:

```
$("#products").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "products", locals: { product: @products } %>");
```

depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: hey Timmy where I will put remote true.. ?? for ajax if I am using rails_admin gem??

Comment: So you are trying to use ajax to paginate more pages? I am not sure about the rails_admin gem but if you use `will paginate` you just add `respond_to do |format| format.js end` in your controller under the index action and then your controller will look to the `index.js` file to get the next page. the way you have set it up, it will put the next page inside of `#products` or if you could do `append`.