# finding Comment by id where comment variable is already set to new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three Models I'm working with. Goal, Comment, and Notation. Goals have many comments and comments have many notations (smaller comments, very much like the comments on the answers here).

I'm trying to display the notations on each comment by appending it with

```
<%= render 'notations/notations' %>
```

This partial loops through each notation to display it:

```
<% @notations.each do |notation| %>
   <%= notation.content %><br />
   Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(notation.created_at) %> ago by 
   <%= link_to notation.user.username, user_path(notation.user) %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that these notations appear on the comments, which appear on the Goal show page, where there is already a new comment form. Take a look.

Goal controller:

```
  def show
    @comments = Goal.comments.order("created_at DESC")
    @comment = Comment.new
    @notations = @comment.notations
  end
```

The `@notations = @comment.notations` doesn't work because I already have @comment reserved for the new one. I've also tried @notations = `Goal.comment.notations` but that gives a no method error for comment. My question is how can I get at the comments being displayed in order to show their notations as well?

Comment: do you iterate over @comments to show each comment?

Comment: I wonder how Goal.comments works in the first place

Comment: @Michael Gorman, yeah, the Goal view pulls in the partial with all the comments, which is basically the same as the notations partial.

Comment: I needed all the notations to show up on all the comments. Goals -> many comments -> many notations. The answer by max pleaner below solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414038/2981429) seems to be what you're looking for. There is a way to pass a *local* (not *instance*) variable to the partial. That way you can use `comment` and not worry about the collission with `@comment`.

Here's an example:

```
<!-- on goal show page -->
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <!-- show the comment content then show the partial -->
  <%= render 'notations/notations', comment: comment %>
<% end %>

<!-- in partial, you now have access to comment -->
<% notations = comment.notations %>
<% notations.each do |notation %>
  <!-- show the notation -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: @ddonche To improve performance you should use `Goal.comments.order("created_at DESC").includes(:notations)` ... this will "preload" the comments so you make 1 DB query for all of the comments' notations, and not a separate query for each comment