# Error getting user's name when put in a modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a webiste where people can debate with each other. It has 4 main models - post, for_the_motion, against_the_motion, and user( added in the respective order). I ran a migration and made a association between for model and against model.

For each view in "for" model I want to show which user added that particular motion. But I am getting an error

> undefined method `image_url' for nil:NilClass

This works fine as long as I keep the for_form and against_form in the main code. If I migrate the forms to a modal it shows the nilClass error. All the post, fors and against have the user_id and post_id attached to them.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :posts
has_many :fors
has_many :againsts
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
            user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
            user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
            user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
            user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls'][user.provider.capitalize]
            user.save!
            user
    end
end
```

end

**for.rb**

```
class For < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post, optional: true
 belongs_to :user,optional: true 
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :fors, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :againsts, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

**against.rb**

```
class Against < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional:true
end
```

CONTROLLERS

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def land
end

def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title)
end

end
```

fors_controller.rb

```
class ForsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @for = @post.fors.create(fors_params)
        @for.user = current_user
        @for.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end



  private
    def fors_params
      params.require(:for).permit(:content)
    end

end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    begin
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
         # flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
    rescue
            # flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
    end
    redirect_to root_path
end
     def destroy
        if current_user
            session.delete(:user_id)
                # flash[:success] = 'See you!'
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

**This is where I am getting the error**

```
<h1><%=@post.title%></h1>

 <!-- Modal Trigger -->
 <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger"      href="#modal3">Add a Comment</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
 <div id="modal3" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <%= render "fors/form"%>
 </div>
 </div>

<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal4">Add A Comment</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal4" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
     <%= render "againsts/form"%>
</div>
</div>


 <div class="fort">
 <h3>For the motion</h3>
  <% if @post.fors.count>0%>
  <%@post.fors.each do |post_for|%>
   <p><%=post_for.content%></p>
  <p><%=post_for.user.name%></p>
  <%end%> 
   <%else%>
   <h4>No for comments till now</h4>
   <%end%>      

   </div>


 <div class="against">
 <h3>Against the motion</h3>
   <% if @post.againsts.count>0%>
     <%@post.againsts.each do |f|%>
    <p><%=f.content%></p>
    <p><%= f.user.name%></p>
  <%end%> 
  <%else%>
      <h4>No against comments till now</h4>
      <%end%>   
  </div>
```

Here is the github link for any other required information
https://github.com/sarfrazbaig/DebatingSociety2

Comment: I think you are missing the object in  the partial, try passing the user object while rendering partial.Please find this reference, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22414038/4057576

Comment: Tried it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **from_omniauth** in this way

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|

    # do whatever you want to do with user object
    #....

  end
end
```