# Cocoon gem, collection_select don't work with drink_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I've the structure using Cocoon gem, in my app/views/order/_form.html.erb the code below work fine:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:drink_id, @drinks, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a drink") %>
```

But when I using in _drink_fields.html.erb don't work, return this:

> undefined method `drink_id' for # Drink:0x007fd30f9799f8

app/views/orders/_drink_fields.html.erb

```
  <div class='nested-fields'>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.collection_select(:drink_id, @drinks, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a drink') %>
</div>
<%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
</div>
```

app/views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
  <hr>
  <h3>Drinks</h3>
  <div id='drinks'>
    <%= f.fields_for :drinks do |drink| %>
      <%= render 'drink_fields', :f => drink %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add', f, :drinks %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
```

app/views/models/order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :drink, optional: true
  has_many :drinks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :drinks, allow_destroy: true
end
```

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
def set_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

def set_drink
  @drinks = Drink.all
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:number, :drink_id, drinks_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
end
```

Why I received it?
How to do work fine?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Can you share the relevant code for your entire form? That'll help us give you an answer. What have you tried so far?

Comment: what object is in`f` and how this object is associated with `drink`?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more context. Please show the complete form and explain the associations: why is cocoon tagged in this otherwise. If I would be guessing: you have something that `has_many :drinks` and from the error we can deduce a `Drink` does not have a `drink_id`, but then the `@drinks` variable and the collection-select make no sense, please show us more to be able to help you.

Comment: Guys, I used the same reference => https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon, using the order instead of project and using drink instead of task.

Comment: Ahh, how do you render the form? I suspect that the @drinks variable is not recognized refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial

Comment: Unfortunately don't work using render parameters, the unique trouble is :drink_id, @drinks working fine, but in my _drinks_fields.html.erb the :drink_id don't work, if I put the same code `<%= f.collection_select(:drink_id, @drinks, :id, :name) %>` in _form.html.erb, this work well.

Comment: Not sure where you claim you would have copied this from, because there is no `collection_select` in my cocoon examples. Did you check out the example project: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking your association I think you made a mistake there. I see the following

- An order belongs to drink
- An order has-many drinks
- So then follows: A drink belongs-to order then. So a drink can be in only one order?

My guess is you are missing a join table between order and drinks. So add a simple

```
class OrderedDrink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :drink 
end
```

You also need the table, so you will have to add a migration to make it (obviously). 
(you could an amount there: they ordered 5 cola's for instance).

Then in `Order` you get

```
 class Order
   has_many :ordered_drinks, inverse_of: :order 
   has_many :drinks, through: :ordered_drinks

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ordered_drinks 
 end
```

In `Drink` you write

```
 class Drink 
   has_many :ordered_drinks
   has_many :orders, through: :ordered_drinks 
 end
```

(you might not need those relations, to know in how many orders a drink was/is)

And then instead of editing/managing the `drinks` association, you edit the `ordered_drinks` and your partial/collection-select will behave as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reference, but in this structure that you put, how I use the collection_select? Example: in _drink_fields.html.erb I need to select :drink_id of oredered_drink.rb.

Comment: You do `f.fields_for :ordered_drinks` and your `_ordered_drink.html.erb` partial will look exactly as your `_drink` partial does now (because an `OrderedDrink` actually _has_ a `drink_id` and a `Drink` _obviously_ does not).

Comment: I agree with you, but how I use drink_id or collection_select in order view?

Comment: You agree but it does not work? I do not understand "how do I use" ?? Just write the text? Do you get an error? Please update your answer with what you have now (code/view) and what you are stuck with

Comment: Thank you very much @nathanvda, with this structure that you put, I got it, but I change just a little thing to working fine, in my controller order params: `def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:number, ordereddrinks_attributes: [:id,  :_destroy, drinks_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy,]])
end`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because, there is no `drink_id` method (Which should be correspondent with `drink_id` column in database) on @drinks object. You probably want to use `:id` instead of `:drink_id`

Comment: Yes, but I received an error "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass".

Comment: Does @drinks have any value? (Not a nil value?)

Comment: @drinks received all drinks, working fine, but if I use :id, when click in Create, I received the error msg: Couldn't find Drink with ID=4 for Order with ID=

Comment: And if I used :drink_id, I received error msg when click in new order => undefined method `drink_id'

Comment: You probably have logic problem you need to express in the question. Like what is order relation with drinks, etc

Comment: order has many drinks, and I need select many drinks when create/update an order, my question is why <%= f.collection_select(:drink_id, @drinks, :id, :name, prompt: 'Select a drink') %> working very well when used in _form.html.erb and don't working when used in _drink_fields.html.erb

Comment: I gave you link in the comment section of your question, have a look it probably solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone that helped to solve this trouble, in especially @nathanvda.
My mistake was forget a table to join drink and order, so I recreated the project and besides that drink and order table, I created a ordereddrink table like @nathanvda answered.

app/models/order.rb

```
has_many :ordered_drinks, inverse_of: :order 
has_many :feeds, through: :ordered_drinks

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ordered_drinks, allow_destroy: true
```

app/controllers/orders_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_drink, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def set_drink
    @drinks = Drink.all
  end
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:number, ordered_drinks_attributes: [:id, :order_id, :drink_id, :_destroy, drinks_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy]])
end
```

app/views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<hr>
<h3>Drinks</h3>
<div id='ordered_drinks'>
  <%= f.fields_for :ordered_drinks do |ordered_drink| %>
    <%= render 'ordered_drink_fields', :f => ordered_drink %>
  <% end %>
  <div class='links'>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add drink', f, :ordered_drinks %>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

app/views/orders/_ordered_drink_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select(:drink_id, @drinks, :id, :name, include_blank: false) %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove drink", f %>
</div>
```

If anyone had the same trouble, contact me or send a message.