# How to pass variable from controller to partial view file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send a variable from controller to partial file.
My controller name is `center_controller.rb` and the partial file name is `_view_center.html.erb`.
In controller, I have @notes variable. When I give `<%= @notes %>`, Iam not getting the values,`nil` is coming. Can you help me on that?

center_controller.rb
`def view` 
`@notes = Notes.all render"view_center.html.erb"`
`end`

and In my view_center.html.erb
`<%= @notes %>`
But Iam not getting @notes values, it is `nil`.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails 4 - passing variable to partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242121/rails-4-passing-variable-to-partial)

Answer (score 1):

### IMPORTANT UPDATE!

This is wrong

```
@notes = Notes.all
```

This is right

```
@notes = Note.all
```

Watch out ! When you call a class you want the class name in Singular

---

**First of all you need to name the view to match the controller method.**

View file names, by default, match the controller and action that they are tied to.

- If you call your view (view_center.html.erb) you should name your controller method (view_center) example:

```
#center_controller.rb
def view_center
  @notes = Note.all
end

#views/center/view_center.html.erb
<%= @notes %>
```

**When you want to render a partial that uses a instance variable, you should do:**

```
<%= render 'view_center', notes: @notes %>
```

The [notes: @notes] sends the variable to the partial

**In the partial file you need to do this:**

```
<% notes.each do |note| %>
<% end %>
```

Otherwise, take a look at Rails naming conventions, because usually, controller filenames are plural:
https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e

- centers_controller.rb
- users_controller.rb
- etc

Comment: You example should use `Note.all` rather than `Notes.all` in `center_controller.rb`